# How to get Visual Studio Code working with python installed on WSL

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-3.6, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed python3.6 on wsl and set my VSC integrated terminal to bash in the settings.json

If I set `python.pythonPath: "python3"` the VSC then warn me to select python environment and shows only the python installations on Windows. Is there a way I can add the python3 I installed on wsl to the python environment list in VSC or get rid of the warning?

Also, when I try to Run Python File in Terminal, it uses absolute path `python3 c:/Users/xxx/Code/test.py` which can't open the file in bash since there's no such file or directory. What do I need to change in the VSC settings so it will use `python3 /mnt/c/Users/xxx/Code/test.py`?

Similar issue reported on github regarding [path translation in VSC](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24772).

Or is it better if I just run the python file from bash manually to avoid all the incompatibility issue with VSC and WSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find a work around from similar issues submitted on Microsoft's `vscode` and `WSL` Github repository about php.

To Run Python File in Terminal in VSC, you will need to switch back to `cmd` as your integrated terminal in the `settings.json`

Create a batch file `python3.bat` as follow:

```
@echo off
set v_params=%*
set v_params=%v_params:\=/%
set v_params=%v_params:c:=/mnt/c%
set v_params=%v_params:"=\"%
bash.exe -c "python3 %v_params%"
```

Change `set v_params=%v_params:c:=/mnt/c%` accordingly based on your home. (ex. If you are running python file located in D: change this line to `set v_params=%v_params:d:=/mnt/d%`

In `settings.json` add/change as follow:

`"python.pythonPath": "C:\\path\\to\\bat\\python3"`

To test your settings, create a `test.py` file as follow:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

and right click in VSC to Run Python File in Terminal, the output should be `/usr/bin/python3`

Note: although the bat script worked but in VSC it will still warn you to Select Python Environment

Answer (score 1):

No, You are trying to run a linux program in a Windows program. This doesn't make sense.

You can use the WSL shell in vscode though.
Add this to your user settings or remove the previous one and add this if there is already one.

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"
```

Comment: I've already done that, what I'm trying to do is to run the python file in wsl shell directly within VSC integrated terminal

Comment: @Ricek Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: op already did that, that is part of his problem: running a debug command from launch.json with \ as path delimiter, while he is in WSL/bash which takes / as delimiter.